# How add my proto to DB? (Java, Maven)

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

I use Google Protobuf to communication protocol between mobile app and server class.

Now I want add this proto to DB in JSON (Table Users column Configuration). How I can convert this and add to DB?

```
import "SrvUserStatus.proto";

package xxxx;

option java_package = "xxxxx";
option java_outer_classname = "xxxxConfigurationMessageProtos";

  message ConfigurationMessage {
    message IdleTimeStatus {
      required uint32 idle_time = 1;
      required Status idle_time_status = 2;
    }
    optional IdleTimeStatus idle_status = 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, what language / framework are you using? The exact details will vary by implementation

Comment: @MarcGravell Java,Maven